# Integer overflow with package `IRanges` in `R`

Tags: r, int, integer-overflow, int32, iranges

**Problem**

I am using the package `[IRanges][1]` and am in need to accurately code for very long sequences that overpass 2^31 by about 10-fold.

From the following, it seems that `IRanges` uses `int32`

```
##### INSTALLATION FROM SRC CODE ######
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")

##### CALL PACKAGE #####
require(IRanges)


IRanges(start=1,end=2^31-1) # Works fine

IRanges(start=1,end=2^31)   # Fail
Error in .Call2("solve_user_SEW0", start, end, width, PACKAGE = "IRanges") : 
  solving row 1: range cannot be determined from the supplied arguments (too many NAs)
In addition: Warning message:
In .normargSEW0(end, "end") : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

As this package is often used for DNA sequences, It would be very useful to be able to be able to deal with values that are greater than 2^32 (≈ 10^9) as many organisms have genome size longer than that.

**Question**

- Am I right to think that this is an integer overflow issue?
- Do you encounter the same issue?
- Is there a way around this problem?

  - Is it possible (and easy) to find the source code and just modify the object type
  - Do you think there exists another version of this package?

The only solution I found is to accept to reduce my level of accuracy and divide each width by 100... but I am not very happy with decreasing my accuracy.

**R version**

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reaching the limit of the size of an integer that can be represented with R.

```
> .Machine$integer.max
#[1] 2147483647
> log2(.Machine$integer.max)
#[1] 31
```

There are special libraries like [`bit64`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/) or [`gmp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/) that be used to handle, e.g., 64 bit signed integers. However, it is not sure if integers as represented by such packages are compatible with other libraries.

Comment: calling the package `bit64` does not seem to reach higher number within the package `IRanges`. I suppose I'll have to rewrite some of the functionalities of `IRanges` then. THanks

Comment: @Remi.b were you able to find a work-around or did you end up having to edit the `IRanges` source?

Comment: I made my own series of IRanges functions and I just worked with data.frame rather than creating a new class. It was actually very easy (it took maybe 3 hours debugging included). I haven't put this code on github as I don't use github but I should and I will soon.